# AIR application design

Tags: actionscript-3, air, mxml, application-design

I would like to make some AIR application which would be used for tracking jobs inside a company.
The idea is to create some database which will handle all the data and, when other users form other computers modify data, it is always saved on that same 'server'.
So, more than one user can edit same database, and it would be great if all the data is constantly 'refreshed' (if one user edits and saves data, on other users' computer data is instantly updated). Application would be used only in local network.
I have some data in Excel, so I also wonder if AIR can handle it somehow? Or is it better to re-structure the whole db?

So, which kind of db should I use? I've read that AIR likes SQLite very much, which would be good because I work with MySQL...
Is AIR (in combination with SQLite) able to handle ALL my needs (working over network, sharing same db, refreshing data, creating server/client applications or something, etc.)?

Thank you very much for any thoughts!
m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no restrictions on what database you can use. My advice would be to create an interface in PHP or ASP or whatever language you prefer (since the Database is on a server elsewhere, you'll need some sort of network connectivity anyway), and send all requests and modifications through that.

Comment: Right, I understand... But I was aiming to simplify the application as much as possible and to make a desktop application, not web app... I've also read that SQLite can make only one connection at time, so it won't be good for my app... Is it the best option to install some mysql server on a host machine and create client applications which would connect via PHP to MySQL?

Comment: You can have a desktop client, but if you want other people to share the same database, then it needs to be on a server, accessible by everyone, which means having network connectivity. That doesn't mean you have a web app, it means you have a desktop app that connects to a database through a network.

Comment: Thanks one more time for your answer! So, if I follow along and setup some MySQL server, will AIR be able to handle what I intend to do?  
Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The principles is no different to any other kind of application.